# How to transfer data between 2 different flutter apps

Tags: flutter

Guys I am trying to make 2 flutter apps that act as server and client.
The aim of this server app is that it should be able to pass commands to the client app and the client app should execute them (ex. if server app asks to launch youtube or any other app the client app should accept the command and execute it. and the client app should be able to send acknowledgments to the server app).

I thought of using sockets{tcp/ip} but realized that both the phones should be connected to the same LAN.

Here 'both the phones' meaning => I will keep the server app in one phone and the client app in another phone

Is there any way I can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If both apps are to be run in same device then you can take advantage that platform socket [winsocket for windows ] if you need to communicate to different devices then use the online socket tunnel.

> but realized that both the phones should be connected to the same LAN

No this is not necessary if you use the socket provider like socket.io. To get started you can head on to [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: Ok, could you please direct me towards the documentation. so that I can view it. I would really appreciate it if you could name the flutter plugins and material(docs) needed for this project. And by the way thanks for your help

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/realtime-chat-app-flutter-node-js-socket-io-e298cd27fb06 https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client these are some example

Comment: I've seen the documentation but I guess they are using the computer as the server. but in my case, I need the app itself to act as a server. so that I can use it on my phone and send commands to the client app on other phones

Comment: as long as the code runs device doesn't matter, just put the server inside an app, there are many frameworks available in dart run a server

Comment: @UmakanthPendyala You should also spend some time learning and reading. Here you can get on;y the idea not the complete work

Comment: Thanks for the help ill definitely go through the docs